# How return a user object in passport.authenticate (local) when the user has logged in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can I set in the `authController` file that I am logged in to return a user object to me?
I'm trying to do it this way to set `res.json (req.body)` in the `userControllerer` file in`exports.register`, but this probably returns the user when it is not known yet whether he is logged in? And my point is that, as in `authController` is success, it returns the object of the logged in user to me.

**Routes/index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');
const authController = require('../controllers/authController');

router.get('/register', userController.registerForm);
router.post('/login', authController.login);

router.post('/register', 
  userController.validateRegister,
  userController.register
  authController.login
);

module.exports = router;
```

**Controllers/userController.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');

exports.registerForm = (req, res) => {
  res.json(req.body);
};

exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
  const newUser = new User({ email: req.body.email, name: req.body.name })
  await User.register(newUser, req.body.password);

  next()
}
```

**Controllers/authController.js**

```
const passport = require('passport');

exports.login = passport.authenticate('local', {
     failureRedirect: '/login',
     successRedirect: '/'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

use the following implementation:

Routes/index.js

```
router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.send(req.user);
  });
```